# Is there any way to inflate a parametrized layout with ViewBinding?

Tags: java, android, view, androidx

I'm developing a Android Module that contains an `Activity`. In this module, I have a default layout (called `activity_document_detector`).

I want to allow the Module's user to pass a layout parameter (e.g. `R.layout.activity_custom`) to my module.

I used to do it like this:

```java
public class DocumentDetectorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(sdkParameter.getLayoutId());
    }
}
```

But now I want to use [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), whose inflating is like this:

```java
public class DocumentDetectorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ActivityDocumentDetectorBinding binding = ActivityDocumentDetectorBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    }
}
```

**Question is**: How can I receive the layout by parameter? Do I need do receive the binding instead of `@LayoutRes id`?